# Explain why the inertia of a Hermitian matrix is uniquely determined by its rank and signature

Tags: quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

Explain why the inertia of a Hermitian matrix is uniquely determined
by its rank and signature

Inertia of hermitian matrix $H$ denoted as $ i(A) = (i_+, i_{-}, i_0)$

Signature $sig(A)=i_+ - i_-$

The book doesn't metions explicity but I am guessing we are counting multiplicities as well,
that means that if a $9\times 9$ matrix is given having eigenvalues $2,2,0,0,0,-1,-3,-3,-3$

then $i(A)= (2,4,3)$ (please correct me if I am wrong)

I know that for hermitian $A$, $i_0 =0$

Also $A$ is unitarily diagonalisable, so the rank of $A$,

## $$r(A) = i_+ + i_- $$

## $$ sig(A) = i_+ - i_- $$

so I get

## $$i_+ =\frac{r(A)+sig(A)}{2}$$

## $$i_- = \frac{r(A)-sig(A)}{2}$$

Comment: Why do you assume $i_0$ equal to 0? Your proof still can easily be generalized to include $i_0\neq0$.

Comment: @NDewolf determinant of hermitian is non zero so multiplicity of $0$ is $0$. If multiplicity of $0$>$0$ and if we didn't know what it was, then I don't think we can tell inertia of $A$ just by knowing rank and signature

Comment: The determinant is real, but you cannoy say that it is nonzero. The zero matrix for example is clearly Hermitian. If there are zeros, then you would indeed an extra invariant such as the dimension (which I assumed you would also be given)